# How to run a multiple nonlinear regression in Excel or R?

Tags: r, regression, excel

I am very inexperienced with R and have only a limited background with Excel but have some data that I need to run a multiple non-linear regression with. What is the best way to do this? With R or Excel? What commands would I use?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't do it with Excel, but you could at least get parameter estimates with its optimization. You need to use the Solver add-in. If you want least squares fitting of nonlinear functions, it's very easy in R.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use software.

Answer (score 5):

In R, you can use the command `nls()` (see [documentation](http://tinyurl.com/lqmw9zs)). For example, for a multiple regression with dependent variable $y$, an intercept $a$, and predictors $x1$ and $x2$ with coefficients $b$ and $c$, respectively, and data stored in variable `df`:

`nls(y ~ a + b*x1 + c*x2, data=df, start=list(a=-100, b=.15, c=-.02))`

Answer (score 3):

in Excel use Solver Add-in. here's how.

- add one row with all parameters of the model
- populate your observations in rows, perhaps, one column for dependent variables, and one column per each independent variable.
- add one more column for predicted Y, insert Excel formula to compute the prediction using all independent variables on this row AND all parameters on *fixed* parameter row
- add one more column with square of the difference between the predicted Y and and dependent Y on the same row
- at the bottom of this column, sum up all squared errors
- start Excel Solver Add-in
- point its target to square errors
- set minimize option
- select the parameter cells to chage
- Run the thing, it'll change parameters until the SSE is minimized

there's a ton of references in internet, such as this [one](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/leastsquares.asp)